# CoreDumpDirectory isn't working on ubuntu; getting segmentation fault with php

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I'm trying to solve a segmentation fault. This message appears in my apache-error.log:

> [notice] child pid 3979 exit signal
>   Segmentation fault (11)

I've tried disabling some apache and php modules but I'm still getting the same error.

I've also tried putting this in apache2.conf:

> CoreDumpDirectory /tmp/apache2-gdb-dump

and then chmod 777, chown www-data... so that the server can write.

I can see no core-dump files to give me a hint on the error.

Does anybody have an idea why CoreDumpDirectory isn't working on Ubuntu?

> answers: $ ulimit -a 
>   core file size
>   (blocks, -c) unlimited data seg size
>   (kbytes, -d) unlimited scheduling
>   priority             (-e) 0 file size 
>   (blocks, -f) unlimited pending signals
>   (-i) 15863 max locked memory
>   (kbytes, -l) 32 max memory size
>   (kbytes, -m) unlimited open files
>   (-n) 1024 pipe size            (512
>   bytes, -p) 8 POSIX message queues
>   (bytes, -q) 819200 real-time priority 
>   (-r) 0 stack size
>   (kbytes, -s) 8192 cpu time
>   (seconds, -t) unlimited max user
>   processes              (-u) 15863
>   virtual memory          (kbytes, -v)
>   unlimited file locks
>   (-x) unlimited

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally was able to see Apache's core dump in Ubuntu:

1. edit `/etc/default/apport`
2. edit apache2.conf:

   ```
     CoreDumpDirectory /tmp/apache2-gdb-dump
   ```
3. make sure Apache can write to it:

   ```
   # chmod 777 /tmp/apache2-gdb-dump
   ```
4. remove core dump size limit:

   ```
   # ulimit -c unlimited
   ```
5. Optionally, change the name pattern of the core dumps:

   ```
   # echo 'coredump-%e.%p' > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
   ```

To analyse the dump use **`gdb`**:

```
$ gdb apache2 /tmp/apache2-gdb-dump/coredump-x.x
```

To see stacktrace details, in gdb:

```
gdb> where
```

This I did, and I obtained the core-dump.
However, my problem was not solved by looking at the coredump;
it was apparently an issue in my php script.

More info:
http://matrafox.info/apache-child-pid-exit-signal-segmentation-fault.html

Comment: You need to `sudo mkdir /tmp/apache2-gdb-dump` before you chmod/chown it.

Comment: What did you change in /etc/default/apport?

Comment: "gzb": do you mean gdb?

Answer (score 2):

Core dumps are disabled on Ubuntu by default

Try this:

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

"ulimit -a" tells you what the current limit is (0 means disabled)

Comment: it doesn't seem to do anything

>$ ulimit -c unlimited
>$ //nothing happens
>$ sudo ulimit -c unlimited
>sudo: ulimit: command not found
>$ man ulimit
No manual entry for ulimit
> sudo aptitude search ulimit
p cpulimit - limits the cpu usage of a process (??)

Answer (score 1):

Do note that the subdirectory in /tmp will be removed after reboot, causing apache to not start due to configuration errors.

On a second note, the chowning is unnecessary. /tmp is chmodded 777 so anyone can read/write there.

@arod sudo ulimit -c does not work because -c is also an argument of sudo. You need to sudo -s, then ulimit -c