# CoreDumpDirectory isn't working on ubuntu; getting segmentation fault in apache2 error log

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, apache2, mod-wsgi

I am not able to log the apache2 crashes in CoreDumpDirectory on ubuntu 10.10. I am using Django 1.2.3 and apache2 with mod_wsgi. I followed the steps listed in response to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534531/coredumpdirectory-isnt-working-on-ubuntu-getting-segmentation-fault-with-php) question but to no avail. I added - `CoreDumpDirectory /var/cache/apache2/`
at the end of apache2.conf file and then after executing
`'ulimit -c unlimited'`, restarted the apache server. Then I replicated the condition that causes apache error log to show- "`child pid 27288 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)`" but there is no mention of apache2 logging that crash in CoreDumpDirectory and also there is nothing in /var/cache/apache2.

Comment: Is this question programming related?

Comment: I am not sure if its an error in my program or error with some installed packages. After installing **apport** on ubuntu I am seeing error like - `child pid 32016 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /var/cache/apache2` but there is nothing in the directory /var/cache/apache2.

Comment: Just to be specific, there is a url I go to and when I hit refresh continuously the browser shows "server returned an empty response" and when I look at the apache error logs I see this error - `child pid 32016 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /var/cache/apache2` I read that segmentation faults are reported in files when you mention CoreDumpDirectory in apache2.conf, which I did. But I don't see any files being generated in /var/cache/apache2 regarding the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem. The issue was with PyLucene environment being initialized on the run time. I was executing initvm() call everytime a request comes and it was causing segmentation fault. [This link](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-pylucene-dev/201008.mbox/%3CAANLkTin0sDK1nkMWUouOX2r9_3Voo=jqtoNds+dimd4W@mail.gmail.com%3E)  directed that I should do it in .wsgi file and after I did that there were no segmentation faults.

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this problem of mod_wsgi children not dumping core. Long story short: You need to edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and set `fs.suid_dumpable=2`.

### Long story:

Linux prevents dumping core for processes that started as root and then dropped privileges. (This is a security feature, so SUID executables don't leak their memory to the user). Setting suid_dumpable=2 means that core files will be owned by root, so there's no direct security problem there either.

Why this affects mod_wsgi? Apparently mod_wsgi's child processes are forked off from Apache's main process. Apache usually starts up as root, since it needs to bind privileged port numbers like 80, and then drops privileges.

(Original bug report: https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/issues/detail?id=247)

Comment: Quoting that ticket """So I read the core(5) man page and it turns out I have to set sysctl 'fs.suid_dumpable=2', which finally gave me the core file! So turns out this is not a mod_wsgi bug, but an unexpected side-effect of Apache being launched as root and hot the way mod_wsgi starts its daemon processes."""

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton: Thanks, I was going to rewrite my SO response, but hadn't gotten around to it yet. I've updated it now.